# Number of each element from a vector in R

Tags: r, vector, sum

I've got the following vector:

```
47 47 47 47 47 38 25 47 47 38
```

Now I search for a command in R that gives me how many times an element attend in the vector. So here I want to get the following return:

```
47 7
38 2
25 1
```

Does anybody know if there exists such a command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

```
dat <- data.frame(a = sample(1:6, 1000, replace = TRUE))
summary(as.factor(dat$a))

  1   2   3   4   5   6 
160 166 191 170 164 149
```

You get the same result with:

```
table(dat$a)

  1   2   3   4   5   6 
160 166 191 170 164 149
```

Comment: @Silke you might consider accepting one of the answers; this will show future visitors which answer worked best for you

Comment: But now I've got an extra question. I've worked with the table() function, how can I use 7 from my example, how can I extract it? Same question for 47.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by extracting these values. What do you want to do with them?

Comment: What you probably can do is convert it to a data frame: <br> `dat2 <- data.frame(table(dat$a))`

Answer (score 1):

I found the `count` function in the plyr package convenient:

```
library(plyr)
dat = data.frame(a = sample(1:6, 1000, replace = TRUE))
count(dat, 'a')
  a freq
1 1  153
2 2  148
3 3  160
4 4  178
5 5  177
6 6  184
```

Comment: table() for a vector?

Comment: That is also a valid option.